# Gem will_paginate não carrega quando é feito deploy no Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gem

```
Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 3605, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1035/1035), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3605/3605), 7.57 MiB | 71.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3605 (delta 2463), reused 3605 (delta 2463)

-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.5.2
       New app detected loading default bundler cache
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.......
       Fetching additional metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
       Fetching github.com/mislav/will_paginate.git
```

Comment: Por favor, explique melhor o que você está tentando fazer e adicione mais detalhes à sua pergunta. Lembre-se que o esforço de alguém ao responder será diretamente proporcional ao seu esforço em perguntar.

Comment: seria interessante também adicionar o conteúdo do seu `Gemfile`

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido, o problema estava no Gemfile mesmo, a gem estava chamando uma versão errada, ao inserir a versão correta funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Você poderia acrescentar mais detalhes como o problema foi solucionado no gemfile? Depois disso, você pode aceitar sua resposta como a certa, aqui do lado esquerdo.